# How To Develop (not run) .Net application on linux?

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, ide

I was using visual studio for several years for developing .Net application, Now days Iam thinking moving to Linux operating system (Ubuntu for specific)

My application is using the following:
Visual Studio 2013 express
Visual Basic language
WCF Web service
Web API
Reflication
SQL server
HTM, Javascript, JQuery, Jquery plugins

What is the suitable IDE I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Take a trip to the [ask] page

Comment: please add more data about your issue and be specific on the point

Answer (score 0):

You can use MonoDevelop for linux
it is free IDE and support .Net framwork.